# Fast way to read filename from directory?

Tags: python, path

Given a local directory structure of `/foo/bar`, and assuming that a given path contains exactly one file (filename and content does not matter), what is a reasonably fast way to get the filename of that single file (NOT the file content)?

Comment: What alternatives did you benchmark?  There aren't very many choices: `os` and `glob` are the big two.  What did you learn from running `timeit`?  What specific question do you have on the benchmark results?

Comment: I rather meant, "Given that I need a quick solution prohibiting the exercise of running a full-fledged benchmark, what is a reasonably fast way to ..."

I'll edit the title accordingly, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @prometheus: Your comment makes even less sense than the original question.  There are only two choices.  What makes you think one is going to be any faster than another?  Since there are only two, what stops you from running `timeit` twice?  I'm really unclear on why you're asking this here.

Comment: I never asked for a thoroughly benchmarked solution as you imply, but for a simple pointer how to get that filename  because the os.listdir function slipped under my radar, and browsing through the os.path documentation didn't yield a reasonably efficient way to obtain that filename. I hope this clears it up. I made the edit, and I don't see how your repeated questioning of my approach is of any benefit to the thread.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1st element of [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)

```
import os
os.listdir('/foo/bar')[0]
```

Comment: heh... I should have actually thought about it for a second :-p

Answer (score 4):

Well I know this code works...

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    #do something
```

Comment: Thanks, gimel made it even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use glob

```
import glob
print glob.glob("/path/*")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

os.path.basename will return the file name for you

so you can use it for the exact one file by adding your file path :

```py
os.path.basename("/foo/bar/file.file")
```

or you can run through the files in the folder and read all names

```py
file_src = "/foo/bar/"
for x in os.listdir(file_src):
        print(os.path.basename(x))
```